# Downvote an answer

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I noted that if I downvote an answer I lose one point. However I don't understand the reason of this. If I downvote an answer which is wrong, I help the other reader to understand which answers are correct. *Can someone explain me this fact?*

Comment: This question may have an answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/if-downvoting-is-so-important-why-does-it-cost-reputation (not on MSE, though).

Comment: This seems to be a recurrent question here on meta: 
[Deduction in rep for downvoting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25753),
[Why does the person who is downvoting an answer get a downvote himself?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20484)
[-1 for downvote?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11512)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Receiving a downvote is not nice and they should thus not be cast carelessly. As a disincentive against careless or even vindictive downvotes, one had to invest a point to downvote a post (unless it is in CW mode and points are moot).

It is true that this can lead to legitimate votes not being cast, and this is a problem, too. Indeed, at some point it was decided that for question post this point is waived, so that now it is only for votes on answer posts that there is a point to be invested.

In the end it is a trade-off. The current balance works about alright.

Finally, if there is an actual error in a particular answer it will make sense to explain it. The down-vote in addition then becomes not that crucial. This is slightly different for questions, which can be considered as a reason for the different handling.